# Filter on second left join - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables. One consists of customers, one consists of products they have purchased and the last one of the returns they have done:

Table customer

```
CustID, Name
  1,     Tom 
  2,     Lisa 
  3,     Fred
```

Table product

```
CustID, Item
  1,     Toaster
  1,     Breadbox
  2,     Toaster
  3,     Toaster
```

Table Returns

```
CustID, Date, Reason
  1,     2014, Guarantee
  2,     2013, Guarantee
  2,     2014, Guarantee
  3,     2015, Guarantee
```

I would like to get all the customers that bought a Toaster, unless they also bought a breadbox, but not if they have returned a product more than once.

So I have tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM Customer
 LEFT JOIN Product ON Customer.CustID=Product.CustID
 LEFT JOIN Returns ON Customer.CustID=Returns.CustID
WHERE Item = 'Toaster'
AND Customer.CustID NOT IN (
Select CustID FROM Product Where Item = 'Breadbox'
)
```

That gives me the ones that have bought a Toaster but not a breadbox. Hence, Lisa and Fred.

But I suspect Lisa to break the products on purpose, so I do not want to include the ones that have returned a product more than once. Hence, what do I add to the statement to only get Freds information?

Comment: I guess you asked this question yesterday. See here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36293041/select-all-customers-except-if-they-have-another-product-sql

Comment: @SatwikNadkarny Is the same but now he add the returns condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT * FROM Customer
LEFT JOIN Product ON Customer.CustID=Product.CustID
WHERE Item = 'Toaster'
AND Customer.CustID NOT IN ( 
    Select CustID FROM Product Where Item = 'Breadbox'
)
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Returns WHERE Customer.CustId = Returns.CustID) <= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The filter condition goes in the `ON` clause for all but the first table (in a series of `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer c LEFT JOIN
     Product p
     ON c.CustID = p.CustID AND p.Item = 'Toaster' LEFT JOIN
     Returns r
     ON c.CustID = r.CustID
WHERE c.CustID NOT IN (Select p.CustID FROM Product p Where p.Item = 'Breadbox');
```

Conditions on the first table remain in the `WHERE` clause.

As a note:  A table called `Product` that contains a `CustId` seems awkward.  The table behaves more likes its name should `CustomerProducts`.

Comment: Still need the condition for `Returns` where a customer break too many Products. The table products is more like `Sales`. Btw cograts on your 400k mark.

Answer (score 0):

You use conditional `COUNT`

```
SELECT C.CustID, C.Name
FROM Customer C
JOIN ( SELECT CustID
       FROM Products
       GROUP BY CustID
       HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Item = 'Toaster' THEN 1 END) > 1 
          AND COUNT(CASE WHEN item = 'Breadbox' THEN 1 END) = 0 
     ) P   -- Get customer with at least one Toaster and not Breadbox
  ON C.CustID = P.CustID
JOIN ( SELECT CustID
       FROM Returns 
       HAVING COUNT(*) < 2
     ) R   -- Get only customers with less than 2 returns
  ON C.CustID = R.CustID
```